# Escaped being dashed / escaped from being dashed

Tags: exam-questions

Why is it that we don't use **from** after **escape** in the following sentence ?

> No one knows, how he escaped being dashed to pieces .

Is there any grammar rule like we have to use helping Verb after *escaped* ? I am not a native speaker but to my ears the sentence with *from* sounds better : *No ones knows, how he escaped from being dashed to pieces.* I know its wrong but just want to know the grammar rule for it.

Answer (score 1):

"Escape from" most often takes a place:

> Houdini escaped from the coffin.

Otherwise, the "from" is dropped, and the meaning is usually "avoided":

> The criminal escaped detection.
>
> I escaped having to talk to my father-in-law.

There are certainly marginal cases. But "escaped from being dashed to pieces" is unnatural. Oh, and "escape from" appears in some set phrases, such as "escape from harm".

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is typically used in the following sentence structure: 
"Escape from [something] to [somewhere]"

E.g.,

- Tom escaped from the disaster
- The survivors escaped the monster to a hidden cave